# PREG_REPLACE EXCEPT a SPECIAL CAR

Tags: php, preg-replace, except

I am looking for a way to preg_replace() every chars except "-"

```
preg_replace ('#[^.0-9a-z]+#i', '', $string);
```

I would clearly like to replace all bad chars except the a-Z0-9 AND "-"

Result done :

$string = preg_replace ('#[^.0-9a-z]/[^-]/+#i', '', $string);

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/[^-]/', '', $string);
```

Will replace everything but `-`.

`[]` denotes the set of items, `^` is the not operator. So when you put in `[^-]` you are saying "give me everything that is not in this set, which in this case is `-`.

Comment: Would be nice to explain why. Also don't believe you need the `\\` in there.

Comment: You forgot your delimiters. Won't work without them.

Comment: Sorry i did not make a good explication...
I would like to replace every chars except 0-9a-Z and -

objective is to clear urls for sitemap

Comment: If i well understand should be :
 preg_replace ('#[^.0-9a-z]/[^-]/+#i', '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Just add the dash in the character class:

```
preg_replace ('#[^.0-9a-z-]+#i', '', $string);
//               here ___^
```